# 'Fail on Standard Error' option ignored during deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've recently had an issue using Azure DevOps pipelines when deploying a release.

I'm using a set of Tasks to take a VM snapshot, install the application, start services to multiple websphere application servers in parallel and then delete the VM snaps if release is successful.

The 'delete snapshot' step is marked to run 'only when all previous jobs have succeeded' and the application install step has the 'Fail on Standard Error' checked in the Task's Advanced option.

The release deployed successfully to 1 server and failed on another because the service didn't start. both the checks were then ignored and the snapshot was deleted.

How can I get the Pipeline to fail when any one node has failed, instead of all of them?

Comment: Have you specified the conditions? Please see [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts&tabs=designer) for details.

Comment: Thanks @AndyLi-MSFT

Comment: Yes, I've specified the "Only when all previous tasks have succeeded" condition on the final delete snapshot step.